# How to add properties to an object, where it defined in a function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Sorry, but i don't know how to ask the question better. The situation is that i use the react-beautiful dnd where the style is defined within a function, which returns an object. The code:

```js
//...
<div
    ref={provided.innerRef}
    {...provided.draggableProps}
    {...provided.dragHandleProps}
    style={getItemStyle(
    snapshot.isDragging,
    provided.draggableProps.style
    )//and i want here to add properties to the style object
    }
>
//...
```

I don't want to edit the `getItemStyle`, but i want to add more properties. The problem is that the `getItemStyle` is the same at every element, but i want to add unique properties to every element. How to add?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `getItemStyle` function is returning an object you can expand or override the object with [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

**Sample**

```
Object.assign({}, getItemStyle(snapshot.isDragging, provided.draggableProps.style), { backgroundColor: 'red' })
```